# Attribute validation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, data-validation

I'm struggling to find a great example of attribute validation in QGIS.
I have existing data created in Autocad Map. It contains some errors.
I'd like to check text fields match a code in a lookup table.
ie for the field 'FP_TYPE' valid attributes are {'SP', 'RP', 'TP'}
Anything else isn't valid and I'd like it flagged.

I don't want to do this using a selection expression, if possible.
I'd prefer to use something like style.
I've tried using field constraints.
I've set up a field constraint using an expression and checked enforce constraints.
Then copied the style to my erroneous shapefile. The erroneous attributes aren't flagged in any way. So I presume I'm using the constraint feature incorrectly.

Does anyone have great instructions on how to set up attribute validation in QGIS?
There's plenty of instructions on setting up the forms for creating new features with attributes from a drop down list but that doesn't seem to apply to checking existing features.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this with styling is a good suggestion and is something I have done in the past.

You can used **Rule-based** symbology to achieve this.

***Layer Properties > Symbology > Rule-based***

Create a rule for the acceptable values of each field, then create an **ELSE** to capture all the invalid values.

In your case:

- Create a rule with the Filter, set the style to a green:

  `"FP_TYPE" IN ('SP', 'RP', 'TP')`
- Create a rule with **Else** radio button checked, set the style to a red. A catch-all for other features i.e invlaid ones.

All the geomtery with valid values will appear green, all the ones with other values will appear red.

We can add as many different validation rules as we like, i.e. referencing different fields.

[image: ValidationWithRules]

Comment: Great! The same expression could also be used to create a new attribute `flag` with field calculator. In this case, the information is stored in the data and thus software- independent. It makes it also possible to filter based on this attribute.